How to do hostname verification in Java for custom protocols?
We are using custom protocol over sockets. With TLS we cannot use setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm() as its arguments can be HTTPS or LDAPS .
How to do hostname verification in case of custom protocols ?
Do we need to use HostnameVerifier class by overriding verify() method ? If so, how can we get hostname from custom protocol URL ?

With a custom protocol, you are on your own. AFAIK host name verification is not built into TLS as such, but comes with higher-level protocols. If you have a custom protocol and it doesn't support it, you need to make do without it or add it. You should be able to get a lot of inspiration from HTTP though.

It should be possible to retrieve the leaf certificate, and then you can access the correct elements. Problem is, I forgot how to do that in Java :/

I see two "close votes", probably by people that don't understand the question. If something is missing then please comment.

If you use a custom non-HTTP bases protocol, I guess in the end you are establishing a javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket connection. SSLSocket has getSSLSession() which gives you an SSLSession which can be queried to get various details about the SSL/TLS connection.
Also an SSLSession is exactly what HostnameVerifer needs to verify a host. Thus you should be able to use HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier() to get the default verifier instance and can use it to verify if the hostname you used for establishing the connection matches the server certificate.
Therefore after establishing the SSLSocket connection it should be possible to verify the hostname this way (code not tested):
String hostname = "example.org";
SSLSocket socket = ... // establish SSLSocket to <hostname>

HostnameVerifier verifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
verifier.verify(hostname, socket.getSession());

